# Как выполнить хранимую процедуру PostgreSQL в Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, asyncpg

Для примера создадим такую процедура, в которой есть и commit и rollback операции

```sql
create or replace procedure a2(
    in a smallint,
    out b smallint
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    
    b:=1;

    if (a=1) then
        commit;
        return;
    end if;
    if (a=2) then
       rollback;
       b:=2;
    else
        b:=3;
    end if;
END; $$;
```

Если выполнить эту процедуру через, средства разработки для баз данных(DataGrip), то она будет выполняться без ошибок.

```sql
CALL a2(1::smallint,null::smallint);
CALL a2(2::smallint,null::smallint);
CALL a2(3::smallint,null::smallint);
```

Но если выполнять туже самую процедуру в Python через psycopg2 или asyncpg, происходят разного рода ошибки. Без ошибок выполняются процедуры в которых нет операции commit и rollback, но мне нужен такой функционал.

```py
ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(
      user="postgres",
      password="denis",
      host="127.0.0.1",
      port="5432",
      database="testing_xab2"
)

cursor = ps_connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc('a2', [72, 10])
result = cursor.fetchall()
print()

""" Ошибка
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function a2(integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM a2(72,10)
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
"""
```

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncConnection, AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy import text

import asyncio


async def main(url, raw_sql):
    engine = create_async_engine(url, encoding='utf8')
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        cursor = await conn.execute(text(raw_sql))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)

asyncio.run(main(
        'postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:denis@localhost:5432/testing_xab2'
        , 'CALL a2(2::smallint,null::smallint);'
    )
)

""" Ошибка
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.Error) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidTransactionTerminationError'>: invalid transaction termination
[SQL: 
        CALL a2(2::smallint,null::smallint);
        ]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно включить авто коммит

Для asyncpg это делается так (Взял пример из https://python-gino.org/docs/en/1.1b2/explanation/sa20.html)

```py
async def main(url, raw_sql):
    engine = create_async_engine(
        url, encoding='utf8', 
    # ВОТ ВКЛЮЧАЕМ АВТО КОММИТ
     isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"
    )
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        cursor = await conn.execute(text(raw_sql))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
```

Для psycopg2 (взял пример из https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/857)

```py
def main2():

    ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(
        # dsn=SQL.URL
        user="postgres",
        password="denis",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port="5432",
        database="testing_xab2"
    )
     # ВОТ ВКЛЮЧАЕМ АВТО КОММИТ
    ps_connection.autocommit = True
    cursor = ps_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('CALL a2(2::smallint,null::smallint);')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
```

БОНУС для использования в session

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

async def main(url, raw_sql):
    engine = create_async_engine(url, encoding='utf8', isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
    async_session= sessionmaker(engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)    
    async with async_session() as session:
        cursor=await session.execute(raw_sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
```